# Inserting data into MS Access table using c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert, odbc

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this code? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
OdbcCommand command = myConnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = 
     "INSERT INTO Table1(type, from, to, depart, arrival, remain) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(10, 7, 00);
DateTime t = new DateTime(2016, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "test");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", "tet");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", "te");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depart", t);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arrival", t);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remain", 4);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You are mixing named and positional parameters.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Generally your code looks ok. So what's wrong with it? Are you getting an exception or some unexpected result?

Comment: I am getting this exception:  ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: *Still getting the same error* - what error is that then? Do you not think that might be a useful piece of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [Access reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) `type` and `from` as column names in your table.

This can be a reason why you're getting such an error.

You can wrap such a column names with square brackets and change your command text to:

```
INSERT INTO Table1([type], [from], to, depart, arrival, remain) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: @Wagner'P If answer was helpful to you - you can mark it as accepted. This can indicate possible solution to someone who will experience such a problem in future. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for details.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @Wagner'P well, it was described in the article I've linked in previous comment: "*To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in*"

Answer (score 0):

This is coding for web application insertion function:

Coding:

```
    string dataPath = Server.MapPath("Your DataPath");
    string ConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dataPath + ";Persist Security Info=True";            
    OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(ConString);
    OleDbCommand Command = Con.CreateCommand();
    Con.Open();
    Command.CommandText = "Insert into Table1(type, from, to, depart, arrival, remain) Values (@type, @from, @to, @depart, @arrival, @remain);      
    TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(10, 7, 00);
    DateTime t = new DateTime(2016, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "test");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", "tet");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", "te");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depart", t);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arrival", t);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remain", 4);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Con.Close();
```